# Horazontal scroll bar moving a picture box Microsoft VB

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have a little pong game im making and I want to make the "Paddle" which is just a picture box move up and down when I move a scroll bar left and right. My code for the Scroll Bar is here:

`Private Sub HScrollBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handle HScrollBar1.Scroll
Me.picPlayer1.Location = New Point(Me.picPlayer2.Location.X, Me.picPlayer2.Location.Y - HscrollBar1.Value * 1)
End Sub`

The paddle only seems to go up, but when I move the paddle to the left shouldn't it go down? Have the default value set for 50 and the maximum at 100

Answer (score 2):

Its because you need to account for which way the the scroll is happening. You'll always return a positive number with the code you have, instead you need to subtract from its current position.

```
 Private Sub HScrollBar1_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles HScrollBar1.Scroll

    Dim NewPos As Integer = e.NewValue
    Dim OldPos As Integer = e.OldValue

    Debug.WriteLine(NewPos, "My Current Value")
    Debug.WriteLine(OldPos, "My Previous Value")

    If NewPos > OldPos Then
        'Moving Up
        Me.PicPlayer1.Location = New Point(Me.PicPlayer1.Location.X, Me.PicPlayer1.Location.Y - HScrollBar1.Value * 1)
    Else
        'Moving Down
        Me.PicPlayer1.Location = New Point(Me.PicPlayer1.Location.X, Me.PicPlayer1.Location.Y - HScrollBar1.Value * -1)
    End If

End Sub
```

Another Solution I found to work better...

```
  Private Sub HScrollBar1_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles HScrollBar1.Scroll

        Dim NewPos As Integer = e.NewValue
        Dim OldPos As Integer = e.OldValue

        Debug.WriteLine(NewPos, "My Current Value")
        Debug.WriteLine(OldPos, "My Previous Value")

        Dim delta As Integer = Math.Abs(NewPos - OldPos)

        If NewPos > OldPos Then
            'Moving up
            Me.PicPlayer1.Location = New Point(Me.PicPlayer1.Location.X, Me.PicPlayer1.Location.Y - delta)
        Else

            'Moving down
            Me.PicPlayer1.Location = New Point(Me.PicPlayer1.Location.X, Me.PicPlayer1.Location.Y + delta)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I figured that I had only positive outputs when I console outed it. But I still couldn't figure it out. I even tried to do old and new position but it wasn't working, one sec ill try this

Comment: there is a delay in the direction change, is there any way I could fix that?

Comment: The "paddle" does not stop and change direction immediately after the HScroolBar changes direction

Comment: I know what the problem is, for some reason my complier isnt compiling my most recent script

Comment: If you point out what part you don't understand I'll elaborate on them in my answer.

Comment: What does delta mean and why did you use absolute value/

Comment: If I wanted to make a limiter to how far up and down the paddle can go and also when I reach that limit, it makes it so I can no longer move the slider that way anymore.

Comment: Make another question specifying the details, and I'm sure we can help, mark this question as answered if you feel the solution is satisfactory.